# ternary operator does not work in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, conditional-operator

I have the following code and I want whenever the list is empty the `td` displays a text and as soon as it gets some elements, show the `element.name` but it only works when the list is not empty (I use console.log(list) to make sure the length is 0)

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="list" class=" w-100">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>header</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    {{ list.length ? element.name : 'the list is empty' }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

the problem is, when the list is empty, nothing will be shown, but as soon as I add something to the list, I can see the name of the elements I have added.
I have also tried using `ngIf` in a `div` and then add another `ng-template` with an else statement.

Comment: @LuísRamalho That's not right. list.length is falsy when it equals 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding your table to `list`. If the list is empty, then there are 0 rows in your table and your ternary expression is never run. Your ternary expression is only ever run when you have a non-empty list.

Instead, use `*ngIf` to hide the table and show the empty message.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="list" class=" w-100" *ngIf="list.length">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>header</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      {{element.name}}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<p *ngIf="!list.length">
  the list is empty
</p>
```

And ternary expressions do work in Angular. Try this:

```html
<p>{{list.length ? 'has rows' : 'does not have rows'}}</p>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-at5wet

Answer (score 1):

If the list is always present (even 0 size) you shouldn't have any issues. If it can be undefined then you need to use optional chaining.

```js
{{ list?.length ? element.name : 'the list is empty' }}
```

Comment: I have declared the list in the TS file and it exists. I can log the list in `ngOnInit`